# Python, optimal way of looping through a file, match two lines after a pattern and then join them

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file which looks like this:

```
(...more lines here...)
:50:SOME RANDOM WORDS
ORDERING ADDRESS LINE1
ORDERING ADDRESS LINE2
:52A:OTHER RANDOM CHARS
(...more lines here...)
```

Now, I also have some simple python lines which loop through a file:

```
with open('some_file.txt') as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if "word" in line:
            # some processing
        if # here I don't know how to process the tow lines from txt
```

How can I match the two lines from `.txt`:

```
ORDERING ADDRESS LINE1
ORDERING ADDRESS LINE2
```

, and join them in a string which will look like this ?

`address_string = "ORDERING ADDRESS LINE1ORDERING ADDRESS LINE2"` ?

**To know:**

- `:50:` will always be as it is but after can be any other words
- `:52A:`will always be as it is but after can be any other words
- there are also lines which don't start with `:` character

Comment: `address_string = ''.join(re.findall(':50:[^\n]+\n([^\n]+)\n([^\n]+)\n:52A', in_file.read()))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want two lines:

```
def sections(fle):
    with open(fle) as f:
        stp = imap(str.strip, f)
        for line in imap(str.strip, stp):
            if line.startswith(":50:"):
                yield next(stp) + next(stp)
                break
```

Output:

```
 In [4]: cat in.txt
(...more lines here...)
:50:SOME RANDOM WORDS
ORDERING ADDRESS LINE1
ORDERING ADDRESS LINE2
:52A:OTHER RANDOM CHARS
(...more lines here...)

In [5]: list(sections("in.txt"))
Out[5]: ['ORDERING ADDRESS LINE1ORDERING ADDRESS LINE2']
```

If you have an unknown amount of lines and repeating:

```
from itertools import takewhile, imap
def sections(fle):
    with open(fle) as f:
        # python3 just use map
        stp = imap(str.strip, f)
        for line in imap(str.strip,stp):
            if line.startswith(":50:"):
                yield("".join(takewhile(lambda x: not x.startswith(":52A:"), stp)))
```

This will grab multiple sections:

```
In [7]: cat in.txt
(...more lines here...)
:50:SOME RANDOM WORDS
ORDERING ADDRESS LINE1
ORDERING ADDRESS LINE2
:52A:OTHER RANDOM CHARS
(...more lines here...)
(...more lines here...)
:50:SOME RANDOM WORDS
ORDERING ADDRESS LINE3
ORDERING ADDRESS LINE4
:52A:OTHER RANDOM CHARS
(...more lines here..

In [8]: list(sections("in.txt"))
Out[8]: 
['ORDERING ADDRESS LINE1ORDERING ADDRESS LINE2',
 'ORDERING ADDRESS LINE3ORDERING ADDRESS LINE4']
```

You can also use double for loops:

```
def sections(fle):
    with open(fle) as f:
        stp = imap(str.strip, f)
        for line in imap(str.strip, stp):
            tmp = []
            if line.startswith(":50:"):
                for line in stp:
                    if line.startswith(":52A:"):
                        yield "".join(tmp)
                        break
                    tmp.append(line)
```

Which will behave exactly as like the previous function.

If you just want the first you can return instead of yield or just call next on the generator:

```
In [25]: next(sections("in.txt"))
Out[25]: 'ORDERING ADDRESS LINE1ORDERING ADDRESS LINE2'
```

Comment: Thanks @PedraicCunningham, unfortunately Python 3 doesn't support `imap()`. Any alternatives to that ?

Comment: @Alex, yep just use map

Comment: Thanks, the last one did the trick, but I have one more question: if there are two sections which start with `:50:` and `:52A:`, how can I take only the first section ?

Comment: I added and example using `next()` to pull just the first, you can replace yield with return if you only want the first but using the generator function would allow you to get all the sections if you wanted or just one if you call next or indeed the nth if you called next x times

Comment: Nice usage of `next()`. However when I try to access the second section it doesn't work. I mean, it prints the first one. As you said, I called `next()` two times.

Comment: You need to assign the gen to a variable and call next on that